# Beyond Compare to hide missing lines on diff file view

Tags: beyondcompare

I would like to hide 'missing lines' on diff file view so that I can read code without breaks.
Araxis merge and Eclipse diff viewer work this way.

Comment: Define *missing lines*.

Comment: if line was 'deleted' you'll see 'missing line' in file diff viewer. I want them to disappear (to be folded for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond Compare (v4) doesn't support displaying comparisons with the gaps collapsed.  I've added your comments to our feature request list, but we haven't received a lot of requests for it yet, so it's not currently planned.

Comment: I think those just stick to araxis merge having this functionality as a 'native feature'. I'm almost 10 years in software development and as of 'merging two files' there were always two ways for me the 'araxis way' and the 'beyond compare way'. I tend to use beyond compare because of handy features to work with directories, it integrates with my favorite file manager and it has configurable shortcuts 'for everything'. But as of 'reading differences' in file I would switch to 'araxis way'. I've seen diff viewers in Eclipse, Idea, NetBeans and I can see the same approach.

Comment: If only you could provide another diff approach as a configurable option I believe you can 'win' some audience.

Comment: I agree, both that making it configurable would be optimal, and that people who prefer the collapsed view likely just use a different product.  Our current data structures make it difficult, but it is something I hope we address in the future; I just wanted to be clear on where it currently stands.